# Multiple process execution and Ordering issues in docker-compose

Tags: bash, process, apache-zookeeper, race-condition, docker-compose

I am trying to launch a zookeeper server and a bootstrap process for my API and another process which has to consume data written by my API to the zookeeper server using docker-compose.

Once I execute docker-compose up, my zookeeper server launches successfully and my bootstrap API is able to connect to it and is able to write data successfully.

The constraint here is that my 2nd process needs to wait for my API to write the data to the zookeeper otherwise it results in an exception since no node would have been created by the API until then. Thus, in the command section of my docker-compose.ml file, I executed a bash command and made my bootstrap API run infinitely by adding a while loop so that the program doesn't exit and also added a sleep statement in my second process so that it waits until the API has done its job. (sort of race condition handling).

From what I understood, docker-compose handles the ordering using "links" in the docker-compose.yml file but doesn't handle the state of individual processes which need to be launched. By state I mean, that the 2nd process needs to start once 1st process has exited successfully.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file -

```
zookeeper:
  image: xyz.com/temp
  ports:
    - "10000:2181"
bootstrapapi:
  image: xyz.com/temp1
  command: /bin/bash -c "cd /code; make test_data ZK_HOSTS=zookeeper:2181 CLUSTER=cluster ; while [ true ]; do sleep 5; done"
  volumes:
    - .:/test
  links:
    - zookeeper
xyz:
  image: def.com/temp2
  command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 10;python -m test --zk-hosts=zookeeper:2181 --zk-cluster-path=cluster "
  links:
    - zookeeper
```

If you need any more details, I'll be glad to let you know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved my problem was to use shared volumes between containers, where the first process creates a new file on this volume after it has done it's job and the other process runs a loop to check if this file has been created. Once the 2nd process detects that, it starts its job of consuming that data.

That was a simple way of solving this producer-consumer race condition scenario in docker-compose using bash scripting in docker-compose. Hope this can helpful.